# How do I put a success step to a job when there are parallel transformations?

Tags: jobs, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have a job which includes sequencial 3 jobs that each makes around 20 parallel transformations. If I have a success step for each transformation the success step which gets the first input gets triggered, but I need JOB2 to start working after every transformation ends in JOB1. Do I just not put a success step in any of the jobs or is there another way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you put JOB2 as next entry for the 20 parallel transformations doesn't it get executed 20 times? Or do you mean that you need JOB2 to get executed just once, after all 20 transformations have finished?

If you need to execute JOB2 20 times, then you just connect JOB2 to the 20 transformations: [image: JOB2 executed for each successful transformation]

If you need to execute JOB2 just once, when all 20 transformations have finished succesfully, and not to execute if one or more of the transformations finish with an error, then you create JOB1 with the 20 transformations and no need of a Success step (it is not mandatory), it will end succesfully when all the transformations finish successfully:[image: JOB1 with transformations executing in parallel]

And then you create a third job to run first JOB1 and then JOB2 when JOB1 has finished successfully:[image: JOB2 executes when JOB1 finish]

Comment: I need to execute JOB2 once when all the transformations in JOB1 have finished successfully. You answered all that so clearly, thank you very much.